# JWT doesn't expire (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I'm using passport-jwt Strategy to verify token.

```
const options = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey: config.jwtSecret
}

const JwtLogin = new JwtStrategy(options, (jwt_payload, done) => {

    User.findOne({_id: jwt_payload.sub}, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return done(err, false)
        }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, user)
        } else {
            return done(null, false)
        }
    })
})
```

So far I can easily generate this token using function `generateToken(user)`

```
    const _id = user._id

    const expiresIn = '1m'

    const payload = {
        sub: _id,
        iat: Date.now()
    }

    const signedToken = jsonwebtoken.sign(payload, config.jwtSecret, {expiresIn: expiresIn})

    return {
        token: "Bearer " + signedToken,
        expires: expiresIn
    }
}

module.exports.generateToken = generateToken
```

And to test this token I use `router.get('/protected')`

```
router.get('/protected', passport.authenticate('jwt',{session: false}), controller.protected)
```

To check this API I send `Bearer <token>` in Authorization header
[image]

Everything works great except every token I create doesn't expire (I've tried many options, including '15s' or just 'ms').

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've just done it, thanks for your advice!

Comment: Check the token payload, is expiration being set? What date is it? just paste your token in https://jwt.io/ to check that or paste a recently generated token in your question

Comment: Also, you are adding the JWT strategy to passport, right? passport.use(JwtLogin)

Comment: I've checked jwt.io, it says that this particular token has 10 seconds expire date but still I can easily access 'protected' route with it.
(Yes, I do use passport.use(JwtLogin))

Comment: But every time I create this token and verify it on jwt.io - it shows different time region with correct exp time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the video I've watched, before setting `payload` to `jsonwebtoken.sign(...)` programmer created variable `payload`:

```
const payload = {
   sub: _id,
   iat: Date.now() // and this line ruined everything for me
}
```

I've just discovered that it sets wrong month, day and time and that was the main problem why my JWT token had wrong expire date.

I solved this problem just by deleting line `iat: Date.now()`.
Also, if you are signing new jwt token - you don't need to set `iat` by yourself. `jwt.sign()` will do it for you

My final `generateToken` function:

```
function generateToken(user) {
    const _id = user._id

    const expiresIn = '10s'

    const payload = {
        sub: _id
        // no longer has "iat"
    }

    const signedToken = jsonwebtoken.sign(payload, config.jwtSecret, {expiresIn: expiresIn})
    // .sign method will generate "iat"

    return {
        token: "Bearer " + signedToken,
        expires: expiresIn
    }
}
```

Also try to use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) in order to check if payload and expire date in your token are good.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a number to represent seconds (for example use `15` for 15 seconds)

**OR**

You can use a string to represent milliseconds (for example `"15"` for 15 milliseconds)

**OR**

You can specify days or hours. This is from jsonwebtoken's documentation:

`Eg: 60, "2 days", "10h", "7d". A numeric value is interpreted as a seconds count. If you use a string be sure you provide the time units (days, hours, etc), otherwise milliseconds unit is used by default ("120" is equal to "120ms").`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback